# Gsoap header include subscriptionId

Tags: gsoap

I need to insert in soap header the "subscriptionId" obtained from the call "CreatePullPointSubscription".
In my header don't have a reference about this.

This is my header structure :

```
struct SOAP_ENV__Header
{
public:
    char *wsa5__MessageID;  /* optional element of type wsa5:MessageID */
    struct wsa5__RelatesToType *wsa5__RelatesTo;    /* optional element of type wsa5:RelatesTo */
    struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__From; /* optional element of type wsa5:From */
    struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__ReplyTo;  /* mustUnderstand */
    struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__FaultTo;  /* mustUnderstand */
    char *wsa5__To; /* mustUnderstand */
    char *wsa5__Action; /* mustUnderstand */
    struct chan__ChannelInstanceType *chan__ChannelInstance;    /* optional element of type chan:ChannelInstanceType */
    struct _wsse__Security *wsse__Security; /* mustUnderstand */    
public:
    int soap_type() const { return 42; } /* = unique type id SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header */
};
```

How to include subscriptionId field ?

Comment: If the SOAP_ENV_Header has a class containing one item then the WSDL says that the header contains only a message id.  It would help greatly if you could post the relevant part of the wsdl.